# Unable to close popup frame

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I'm currently creating a program that will open a popup window for the user to confirm their actions.

```
    def ConfirmActions():
        popup = tk.Toplevel(window)
        popup.geometry("500x100")
        popup.title("Confirmation")

        def DeletePopup():
            popup.pack_forget()

        def PerformAction():
            #code that performs the desired action
            DeletePopup()

        def Widgets():
            confirmation = tk.Label(popup,
                             text="Are you sure?",
                             font=("comic sans", 12))
            confirmation.place(x=250, y=20, anchor = 'center')

            confirm = tk.Button(popup,
                             text="Yes",
                             width = 10,
                             command = PerformAction,
                             font=("comic sans", 12))
            confirm.place(x=100, y = 60)

            deny = tk.Button(popup,
                             text="No",
                             width = 10,
                             command = DeletePopup,
                             font=("comic sans", 12))
            deny.place(x=300, y = 60)

        Widgets()
```

However, whenever the subroutine for closing the window is run I get this error message

> Exception in Tkinter callback
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 1892, in **call**
> return self.func(*args)
> File "C:\Filepath", line 945, in PerformAction
> DeletePopup()
> File "C:\Filepath", line 941, in DeletePopup
> popup.pack_forget()
> AttributeError: 'Toplevel' object has no attribute 'pack_forget'

I don't want to use .destroy() as this popup screen should be able to be used multiple times when the program is running and destroying the screen will make it unable to be recovered

Edit: I have decided to use .withdraw() and .deiconify() to hide and display each frame

Comment: Have you read the documentation of `pack_forget()` ? Because I never saw it in the way you use it.

Comment: Have you tried using `popup.forget()`?

Comment: Try `popup.destroy()` instead of `popup.pack_forget()`, unless you want to reuse popup.

Comment: @Derek I do want to reuse the popup so **popup.destroy()** would not be useful. I have decided to use **popup.withdraw()** instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since you wish to reuse the popup window, you may find this code snippet useful.
It will open and close popup window by harnessing `popup.protocol` and Key-F2.

I've also included a master close function using `master.protocol` and Key-Escape.

```py
import tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()

master.wait_visibility()

popup = tk.Toplevel(master)
popup.withdraw()
popup.transient(master)


def closer(event = None):
    master.destroy()


def toggle(event = None):
    """Toggle switch for toplevel"""
    if popup.winfo_viewable( ):
        popup.withdraw( )
        master.focus_set( )
    else:
        popup.focus_set( )
        popup.deiconify()

# Bind master to closer functon via EXIT button, Alt+F4 and Escape Key
master.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", closer)
master.bind("<Escape>", closer)

# Bind popup to toggle function via EXIT button, Alt+F4 and Key-F2
popup.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", toggle)
popup.bind("<F2>", toggle) # access in popup
master.bind("<F2>", toggle) # access in master

master.mainloop()
```